# New columns with list of columns of databse tables

Tags: python, database, pyspark, databricks

I have a DataFrame with a column with all the table names in my database of Databricks:

%sql
SHOW TABLES FROM default

| tableName |
| --- |
| table1 |
| table2 |
| table3 |

I wanted to add a column with a list of columns of each table:

| tableName | tableColumns |
| --- | --- |
| table1 | col1,col2,col3 |
| table2 | col1 |
| table3 | col1,col2 |

I can obtain the columns like this: spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table1").columns

But I would need a function that iterates each row.

Anybody? Thanks in advance

Comment: there usually is an internal table that stores all database-table-column details. you could try to find that (something like `information_schema`)

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Iterating over the rows of a DataFrame? Calling the function you mentioned for each value? Taking the resulting values and adding them to a new column in your DataFrame? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get that using a single Spark call, but you can just loop over tables in Python and collect column information one by one.

```py
tables = [row["tableName"] for row in spark.sql("show tables from default").collect()]
tablesWithColumns = [[t, ",".join(spark.table("default." + t).columns)] for t in tables]
display(spark.createDataFrame(tablesWithColumns, ["tableName", "columnNames"]))
```